# Installing jenkins plugins automatically

Tags: bash, scripts, plugins, docker, jenkins

I'm writing a script to download jenkins war, skip setup, then install plugins for it.

I downloaded batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh using some link, and also created the plugins.txt file as mentioned.

When i run the script using docker it is giving me an error saying "you must specify plugins.txt".

Here is my script:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Install Java.
RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# get maven 3.2.2 and verify its checksum
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz; \
echo "87e5cc81bc4ab9b83986b3e77e6b3095 /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz" | md5sum -c   
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/ven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# install maven
RUN tar xzf /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz -C /opt/; \
  ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.2.2 /opt/maven; \
  ln -s /opt/maven/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin; \
  rm -f /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz
ENV MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven

    
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install bash git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

# copy jenkins war file to the container
#ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
COPY jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
COPY proxy.xml /jenkins/proxy.xml
COPY config_updated.xml opt/config_updated.xml

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/jenkins.war"]
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

#Install plugins
RUN cd /usr/local/bin && curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgomez/devops-incubator/master/forge-tricks/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh -o batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh 
COPY /plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
```

When I build the image of above script it is giving this error:

```
Step 21/23 : RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
 ---> Running in 72d198deef6b
You must provide plugin file
  usage: batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh options

  Install or update Jenkins Plugins.

  OPTIONS:
     -p --plugins  file containing plugins list
     -x --xplugins   file containing excluded plugins list
     -d --plugindir  directory where to deploy plugins (.jpi)

  Examples:

 **Run:batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh --plugins okplugins --excludedplugins nokplugins --plugindir /var/lib/myjenkins/plugins
The command '/bin/sh -c xargs /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt' returned a non-zero code: 123**
```

FOR checking if I comment that line and change ENTRYPOINT to bash and checked, and found plugins.txt is present in that location only

[image: BASH OUTPUT]

I need to take arguments from plugins.txt and install those plugins to jenkins, when I launch it in browser.

[The article](https://dzone.com/articles/dockerizing-jenkins-2-setup-and-using-it-along-wit) I used for reference.

Thank you in advance, sorry if there wrong english.

Comment: Go to below link, which I found similar what you have asked [You can refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328278/installing-jenkins-plugins-to-docker-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what is wrong with your build, but your Jenkins Dockerfile looks unnecessarily complicated. Here is a simple Dockerfile that does what you want:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

That installs the plugins defined in `plugins.txt`.

This should be enough to install your plugins automatically. However if you want to configure a complete Jenkins instance from a configuration file, check out this [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin) that allows Jenkins to be completely configured from YAML.

Comment: do we have to write the ```install-plugins.sh``` or it comes with  jenkins

Comment: It comes with Jenkins, but you will have to write the 'plugins.txt' file that lists the plugins you want to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [jenkins-plugin-cli](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool) and either start listing the needed plugins with --plugins argument as in

```
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins \
antisamy-markup-formatter \
ant:475.vf34069fef73c
```

Or as mentioned list them in .txt file and use jenkins-plugin-cli --plugin-file argument `jenkins-plugin-cli --plugin-file /your/path/to/plugins.txt`

Either of these approaches should work although personally I tend to use the first one, here's a sample [Dockerfile](https://github.com/theJaxon/jenkins-config-as-code/blob/main/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` works by creating a new command line and running it. The way it creates the command line is by starting the new command line it is creating with the arguments given as the `xargs` command line and then appending the biggest chunk of stdin that it can (remember that if stdin is bigger than the maximum command line length will make it impossible to simply use all of stdin, it must be chopped up to fit inside of valid maximum command line length.)

The script, `batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh`, (I got mine from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgomez/devops-incubator/master/forge-tricks/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh), you should have provided the link to where you got yours from because there could be many variants of that script) does nothing to provide the `-p` option so it dies with missing `-p pluginfile.txt`.

```
RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

Are you sure you should even be using `xargs` here at all?  I think this is what you are really trying to do:

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/batch-install-jenkins-plugins.sh -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

But then you will probably crash because of missing `-z plugindir` option which you should also add to your `Dockerfile`.